# How to add strings and special characters to every row in dataframe in new column?

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
col1
file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv
...
file500.csv
```

for every row in `col1` I need to add more characters and special characters in exactly the same positions regardless of the file name in question.

For a quick test I setup two variables one with the original filename as a string and another where I do the string manipulation like so:

```
original_string = 'file1.csv'


string_manupilation = 'path.path.\"{}\"'.format(original_string)
```

the output of `string_manupilation` is this:

```
'path.path."file.csv"'
```

I need it to look like this, why are the slashes are being removed?:

```
'path.path.\"file.csv\"'
```

If the string manipulation variables work out I can roll them to iterate over the entire dataframe:

for index, row in df.iterrows():
     [string manipulation]

Comment: just do `df['col1'] = 'path.path.'+df['col1']`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I can not do that because I need the back slash in specific positions

Comment: `'path.path.\\' + df['col1'] + '\\'`?

Comment: @QuangHoang this is close but the two double quotes need to remain exactly how i have here `'path.path.\"file.csv\"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you what you need:

**Manipulation**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['file1.csv','file2.csv','file3.csv'], columns = ['col1'])
df['string_manipulation'] = df['col1'].map(lambda x: 'path.path.\\"{}\\"'.format(x))
```

**Output**

```
print(df.to_string())
        col1      string_manipulation
0  file1.csv  path.path.\"file1.csv\"
1  file2.csv  path.path.\"file2.csv\"
2  file3.csv  path.path.\"file3.csv\"
```